# Multiple syntax quotes

Tags: clojure

`a ``a and ```a gives the following

````
user=> `a
user/a
user=> ``a
(quote user/a)
user=> ```a
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote quote)) (clojure.core/list (quote user/a))))
````

Since `a gives user/a, I'd anticipate ``a is the same as `user/a, which is user/a.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: here is a good resource for understanding how quoting behaves https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the evaluation step.

Let's first take a look at the simple quote:

```
user=> 'a
a
user=> ''a
(quote a)
user=> '''a
(quote (quote a))
user=> ''''a
(quote (quote (quote a)))
```

and so on.  This is quite simple because it doesn't need to process the quoted form in any way except read it.

`'a` is read as `(quote a)`, which evaluates to the symbol `a`.

`''a` is read as `'(quote a)`, which is read as `(quote (quote a))`, which evaluates to the list `(quote a)`, which is a list of the two symbols `quote` and `a`.

And so on.

Now, what does `` ` `` do that `'` doesn't?  It is more or less a template mechanism that

- automatically qualifies symbols
- automatically handles auto-gensym
- evaluates things marked by `~` (or `~@`) and re-inserts the results.

This means that it cannot just produce another `quote` form containing the following form, but has to produce an actual function call form at the call site (except in trivial cases).  This form will mostly consist of sequence operations (`list`, `cons`, `concat` etc.) to assemble the template parts with the evaluated bits.  If you then again quote that, you get to see those function call forms.